# How to create a content smooth transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 div, **div1** is actually showing when page loads, **div2** is not, when user clicks **link1** I need to have a smooth transition between **div1** to **div2**.

I've searched and find some workarounds with jquery and other libraries, but I just cant manage to do it right. If someone could help me out it would be great.

Comment: Transition can have many types: fade, move, transform, rotate etc. (styles also)

Comment: It would be really cool if you let the world know what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS3 transitions on properties that will trigger Hardware Acceleration in browsers i.e the CSS Opacity property

```
transition:opacity 1s ease;
```

To trigger the tranisiton just add a hide class to div1 via JS which sets the opacity to zero

```
.hide{opacity:0;visibility:hidden;}
```

Vanilla JS version here http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/L3fg08zp/

with jQuery to toggle the class you could use:

```
$('#change').on('click',function(){
    $("#div1").toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [`jQuery.fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`jQuery.fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). See the "Demo" parts of the page for a demonstration.